# How to script a change to Audio Recording Device Preference at login

Tags: audio, debian, usb, kde-plasma

Current system: KDE/Debian 8 (but same with any Debian variant that I have tried).

I am using an officially non-supported webcam (Logitech C920).  It works in every way that I want.

Except that when I boot, I need to change the Phonon Audio Recording Device Preference in System Settings from the preferred internal sound card.

The C920 is fully functional, recognized just not the preferred one. After simply marking it preferred, it works fine but the setting does not survive reboot.

If I cannot make it survive reboot, how do I script it? Then I can have it done automatically at login time?

If Phonon had a commandline interface, great. But I expect the solution involves another component.  That is fine with me :)  I am just tired of answering the phone on the PC and having no mic because I forgot to manually set it.

I am a pretty deep technical propellorhead but this one is stumping me. It cannot be very hard to do...